# Number of perpendicular diagonals in any regular polygon

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry

> Find the least positive integer *n* such that there are at least $1000$ unordered pairs of diagonals in a regular polygon with *n* vertices that intersect at a right angle in the interior of the polygon.

Here, I thought that *for even* $n$, starting at any vertex, I draw the diagonal joining the opposite vertex. Then we get $\dfrac{n-2}{2}$ diagonals perpendicular to this diagonal. We can draw the longest diagonal $\dfrac{n}{2}$ times and keep getting unique cases. Based on this, I get the inequality,
$$\frac{n}{2}\cdot \frac{n-2}{2}\ge1000 \Rightarrow n \ge 65$$
My argument after this is that $n$ can only be even, giving me the answer as $66$.

> However, how do I prove that $n$ cannot be odd? Or am I making a mistake in my argument and an odd $n$ can give valid answer?

Comment: Your count for even $n$ is incorrect. There is only one pair of diagonals in a square. For an octagon there are $18$ qualifying pairs. You are counting each pair of main diagonals twice, and missing pairs that do not include a main diagonal.

Comment: @MyMolecules No. For $n=10$ it counts only $20$ pairs. There are another $20$ pairs in which neither diagonal passes through the center.

Comment: @DanielMathias Yes, I forgot about the pairs arising from the shorter diagonals. For $n=6$ the formula luckily matched because the shorter diagonals were not counted.

Comment: An evaluation via code gives the results for even $n$ to be OEIS [A002411](https://oeis.org/A002411) @MyMolecules

Comment: @DanielMathias Thank you very much! I will write an answer with proof that for odd no. of sides, number of perpendicular diagonals is zero; for even no. of sides, I will mention the formula in the link you shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim :** $\;$ Inside a regular polygon with an odd number of sides, there are no perpendicular diagonals.

**Proof:** $\;$ Imagine a regular $n$-gon is inscribed in a circle. Suppose four of its vertices $A,B,C,D$ give a pair of perpendicular diagonals.

[image]

This means $m(\overset{\frown}{AB})+m(\overset{\frown}{CD})=m(\overset{\frown}{BC})+m(\overset{\frown}{AD})$ implying that $l(\overset{\frown}{AB})+l(\overset{\frown}{CD})=l(\overset{\frown}{BC})+l(\overset{\frown}{AD})=$ half the circumference.

Then arcs $\overset{\frown}{AB},\overset{\frown}{CD}$ contain one half of remaining $(n-4)$ vertices while other half lies on arcs $\overset{\frown}{AD},\overset{\frown}{BC}$. Clearly $(n-4)$, hence $n$, must be even.

---

The formula $n(n-2)/4$ for even $n$, undercounts pairs of orthogonal diagonals because only longest diagonals (passing through center) have been taken into account. Shorter diagonals (not passing through center) can also intersect at right angles. The correct formula can be found in the [OEIS link](https://oeis.org/A002411) shared by @DanielMathias in comments. To be explicit,

- A regular $(2n+1)$-gon has $0$ perpendicular diagonals.
- In a regular $2n$-gon, the number of diagonal pairs intersecting at right angles is $\dfrac{n(n-1)^2}{2}$

Using this formula in the inequality, one gets $n=14$ i.e., a regular $28$-gon is first one to satisfy the given condition.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add a proof of how we get the correct result?

Comment: @AG_Coder Right now I do not have a proof of the formula. I'm also interested in its proof.